# How to split grouping of xml elements based on their subelement values using xslt 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, split

In an XSL document I need to group **image** elements based on their  value:

- Elements with **size**=*full* should be alone in an **imageset**.
- Elements with **size**=*half* should be in an **imageset** ...

  - in pairs, if there's two adjacent **image** elements having **size**=*half*
  - alone, if not.

This turned out to be surprisingly tricky for me to implement.

For tools, I'm having the standard XSLT 1.0 engine in a .NET 4.8 software.

Source data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<imagecollection>
    <imageset>
        <image>
            <size>half</size>
            <id>a group 1</id>
        </image>
        <image>
            <size>half</size>
            <id>b group 1</id>
        </image>
        <image>
            <size>full</size>
            <id>c group 2</id>
        </image>
        <image>
            <size>half</size>
            <id>d group 3</id>
        </image>
        <image>
            <size>full</size>
            <id>e group 4</id>
        </image>
        <image>
            <size>full</size>
            <id>f group 5</id>
        </image>
        <image>
            <size>half</size>
            <id>g group 6</id>
        </image>
    </imageset>
</imagecollection>
```

I've ended up with this transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="imagecollection">
        <imagecollection>
            <xsl:for-each select="imageset/image[not(preceding-sibling::image[1][size='half'] and size='half')]">
                <imageset>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                    <xsl:if test="following-sibling::image[1][size='half'] and size='half'">
                        <xsl:copy-of select="following-sibling::image[1]"/>
                    </xsl:if>
                </imageset>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </imagecollection>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Indeed I get correct result using the data above:

```
<imagecollection>
    <imageset>
        <image>
            <size>half</size>
            <id>a group 1</id>
        </image>
        <image>
            <size>half</size>
            <id>b group 1</id>
        </image>
    </imageset>
    <imageset>
        <image>
            <size>full</size>
            <id>c group 2</id>
        </image>
    </imageset>
    <imageset>
        <image>
            <size>half</size>
            <id>d group 3</id>
        </image>
    </imageset>
    <imageset>
        <image>
            <size>full</size>
            <id>e group 4</id>
        </image>
    </imageset>
    <imageset>
        <image>
            <size>full</size>
            <id>f group 5</id>
        </image>
    </imageset>
    <imageset>
        <image>
            <size>half</size>
            <id>g group 6</id>
        </image>
    </imageset>
</imagecollection>
```

Yet the transformation fails to handle is this simple data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<imagecollection>
    <imageset>
        <image>
            <size>half</size>
            <id>a group 1</id>
        </image>
        <image>
            <size>half</size>
            <id>b group 1</id>
        </image>
        <image>
            <size>half</size>
            <id>c group 2</id>
        </image>
    </imageset>
</imagecollection>
```

My transformation gives this output:

```
<imagecollection>
    <imageset>
        <image>
            <size>half</size>
            <id>a group 1</id>
        </image>
        <image>
            <size>half</size>
            <id>b group 1</id>
        </image>
    </imageset>
</imagecollection>
```

...so the last one of the three **image **elements is missing.

I tried many things but it's easy to break the logic: Whether an element get a second occurrence or is omitted altogether.
Wondering if I'm missing something simple or if there would be an easier aproach to handle this kind of grouping for a start.

Comment: Your rules are ambiguous: if there are 3 adjacent half images (as in your 2nd example), what determines if they should be paired as 2 +1 or 1 +2? Is there no way to use the `id` value for this?

Comment: True, ruling wasn't explicit. Anyway, 2+1 is what I tried to make it. Fortunately you assumed this way in your clever sibling recursion solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the rule for handling each section of adjacent half-images is to pair them in the existing order, leaving only the last odd one in a set of its own, you could implement it using a technique known as "sibling recursion":

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/imagecollection">
    <imagecollection>
        <!-- start with first image -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="imageset/image[1]"/>
    </imagecollection>
</xsl:template>

<!-- first half of pair -->
<xsl:template match="image[size='half' and following-sibling::image[1]/size='half']">
    <imageset>
        <!-- copy self and other half -->
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="following-sibling::image[1]"/>
    </imageset>
    <!-- skip to sibling after next -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::image[2]"/>
</xsl:template>

<!-- full or standalone half -->
<xsl:template match="image">
    <imageset>
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </imageset>
    <!-- continue recursion with following sibling -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::image[1]"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```